# How to get the actual HTTP Request string before it is sent?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, packet, pcap

I am trying get the actual response string that is being sent from an HTTPWebRequest.

I'm hoping this is embarassingly simple, but as of yet, I have not found a solution outside of  sniffing out the network for that specific packet.

Does anybody have a solution to this ?

```
    public static string GetDataFromHttpWebRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {

    }
```

Something that would fall into this signature.

Comment: The problem is that you want only view (for debug purpose) the http request and response between your application and the web server?

Comment: I want to view the actual GET request so i can later create packets that replicate that request so I can run different types of test on my web server

Comment: You can try with fiddler, is a proxy that log every request. It automatically attach to internet explorer

Comment: I don't really want to use a sniffer